# What I am missing using group by?

Tags: r

I am working with Rstudio on a dataset that includes two treatments and a response that is in Kg. I am trying to summarize and get the mean of `Kg` by `TRT`. However, I got the same values for both responses. My dataset is much bigger than the data enclosed below but are the same variables.

However, when I work with those nine values, I get the real response, but I get the same mean for both when I work with my dataset. The code is the same for both. I have no idea what I am missing.

```
Trt    Kg
 <chr> <dbl>
 CON    38.6
 CON    37.2
 CON    31.3
 CON    33.1
 CON    36.3
 TRT    34.8
 TRT    33.4
 TRT    33.5
 TRT    33.3
 

EXPF <- EXPBW %>%
  group_by (Trt) %>%
  summarize (mean_cw = mean(kg))

View(EXPF)


Second try
```

Clearly when I work with a small dataset works

However, when I work with my real dataset I get the same mean values for the two groups

```
    CW <- tabla  %>%
   dplyr::group_by(tabla$Trt) %>%
   dplyr::summarize(mean_cw = mean(tabla$CBWKg))
    
    View(CW)

    
    tabla$Trt   mean_cw
    GB         37.93381
    CON        37.93381
```

Comment: Try `summarize(mean_cw = mean(Kg))`

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarize(...)`. If this works, then it might be that `plyr` is being loaded in your namespace *after* `dplyr`, thereby masking some of its functions.

Comment: Or ... you can fix your typo: the frame is defined with `Kg` but you are doing `mean(kg)`. My next guess is that you have `kg` defined elsewhere in your environment, and it isn't the same.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in the comments (@r2evans and @kybazzi), you have a typo (i.e., you use lower case `kg` when you have `Kg` in your dataframe) and you may need to be explicit with the `dplyr` package in your functions calls, as it may be trying to use `summarize` from the `plyr` package.

```
EXPF <- EXPBW %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Trt) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(mean_cw = mean(Kg))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Trt   mean_cw
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 CON      35.3
2 TRT      33.8
```

Data

```
EXPBW <-
  structure(
    list(Trt = c("CON", "TRT"), mean_cw = c(35.3, 33.75)),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code that you have provided, and it gives an error message saying that "object 'kg' not found".

You need to fix your code inside `mean()` from `kg` to `Kg`.

Then the code works fine.